# Why is this bmatrix call messed up?

Tags: math-mode, align

I have the following code:

```
        \item First, we show that $\forall n, r=2. s_1 \simeq s_2$. To see this, notice that
            \begin{align}
                s_1(A) &= \begin{bmatrix} A & \\ & I_n \end{bmatrix} \\
                       &= \begin{bmatrix} & I_n \\ I_n & \end{bmatrix}
            \end{align}
```

I am expecting to see the second matrix on the second line in this align environment, but instead, here is what my render output is

[image: actual output]

The rendering is fine if I copy the matrix in the first line (i.e. `\begin{bmatrix} A & \\ & I_n \end{bmatrix}`) after the equal sign. What is going on?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
        \item First, we show that $\forall n, r=2. s_1 \simeq s_2$. To see this, notice that
            \begin{align}
                s_1(A) &= \begin{bmatrix} A & \\ & I_n \end{bmatrix} \\
                       &= \begin{bmatrix} & I_n \\ I_n & \end{bmatrix}
            \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try using display math mode instead of align?

$$s_1(A) &= \begin{bmatrix} A & \\ & I_n \end{bmatrix}$$
           $$\begin{bmatrix} & I_n \\ I_n & \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If I add to your code only what's missing to make it compilable (more precisely, I added `\documentclass{article}`, loaded `amsmath` and enclosed your code in `enumerate` and `document` environments), there are no errors and the output is as expected. Thus, what you see seems to be the result of something you are not showing here. You should complete your example so that it is compilable as is and still reproduces the error.

Comment: I extended your code fragment to be an example but it did not show the problem, please edit the question so that the code shown shows the from in your first image.

Comment: @Nate that would certainly generate syntax errors.

Comment: @Vincent That's interesting that it didn't generate the problem with this minimal example. I suppose it must be something with the stylesheet or some other package I am using. Thank you very much, and I will try to create a minimal example.

Comment: @YuxiL in general it's always best to post the image generated from the code you post, then you know the posted code shows (or does not show) the problem.